# Attaching two separate Python codes

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I have two codes: the first one detects faces from live feed, and the second captures image from WebCam.

I want to attach these codes in a single Python file so first the face is detected and then image is captured for just the face.

Following are the codes:

**Captures face:**

```
import cv2
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Capture frame
ret, frame = video_capture.read()

# Write frame in file
cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', frame)

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
```

**Detects face:**

```
import cv2
import sys

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=2.0,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want these two scripts to work together in a single script.

Regards

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. What is your combined code and what problems exactly are you having with it?

Answer (score 0):

You are close! Just slice the frame array where face x,y position is found. Also if you want to save gray image, replace frame with gray.

**Save only faces from webcam (color)**

```
import cv2
import sys

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=2.0,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags = 0
        #flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        # Write frame in file
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)        
            cv2.imwrite('only_face.jpg', frame[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And as @Antti Haapala said, do not only ask to do something `ASAP`. Tell us which way you have tried and what challenges you are facing.